# Inertial pressure on in a rotating syringe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure, inertia

First question on stackexchange. Hopefully somebody can help me out. I'm struggling to express the following eloquently.

I have a rotating syringe tipped with a needle. rotation speed w, with radius r1 and r2.

Now let us pretend that the needle is blocked, so only r1 matters.

My thinking is, due to inertia the pressure observed at r1 is equal to density x fluid 'height' (in an horizontal sense) x acceleration due to inertia.

I'm struggling to calculate this outward acceleration. I've always been told that centrifugal force doesn't exist. So is inertia equal to the centripetal acceleration? It isn't made entirely clear...

Many thanks in advance, if that is too easy, you could also consider the case where the needle is blocked just at the tip (r2) what would be the pressure there.

[image]

Comment: I have put on a homework and exercises tag as this question is in that category.

Comment: _I've always been told that centrifugal force doesn't exist_ If it would not exist, then there would be no reason for your laundry to become dry in your washing machine.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas From the perspective of an observer standing next to the washing machine, the water is separated from the laundry exactly because there is no force on the water.

Comment: From the perspective of a rotating observer inside the washing machine, a force acts on the water.

Comment: So, seems, that you agree that indeed centrifugal force exists in a non-inertial reference frames. Thus your comment in a post to which I replied is still not valid, cause it implies that centrifugal force does not exist in any reference frames at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it this problem is similar the problem of column of water and the pressure rising due to gravity pulling down on the liquid - in which case pressure, $P$, is given by

$P = h \rho g$

where $h$ is the height of liquid, $\rho$ is the density and $g$ the acceleration due to gravity - but you probably knew this already.

The point I want to make here is that the height of water is important because the forces all add up from top down to bottom (so the pressure at the bottom of the oceans can be very very high - 100s or 1000s or more atmospheres)

Here the issue is the that the force (and hence acceleration) due to the rotation changes - as the radius gets larger the force gets bigger of course.

So calculate the pressure at $r1$ and $r2$ you need to do an integration to add up all the forces for the liquid 'above' $r1$ and $r2$ - so on your diagram you need the height (edit - ah not labelled, but that it is in writing on the diagram.)

The good news is that the formulae for $r1$ and $r2$ will be the same as the cross sectional area of the tube does not matter - but again you need to know the height of liquid - or length of liquid towards the centre.

Finally, Centripetal force = centrifugal - action and reaction... here you can consider the centrepetal force is the same as the force the centrifugal force. Think of it this way, the pressure at $r1$ or $r2$ must provide the inward centrepetal force on the column of liquid above it to make it move in circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

It's instructive to think in the inertial frame too. Consider a small chunk of water in middle of syringe somehere. It is going around in a circle. So, there's net force on this chunk of water directed towards the centre of the circular motion. This force is arising due to difference in forces due to water in front of chunk and water behind the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a mass element $dm$ of water in position $r$ from the center. It has an area $A$ (the cross section of the syringe) and a thickness $dr$. If $\rho$ is the density of water your mass is then

$$dm=\rho A dr$$

Now, what forces are acting on this mass?

On both sides, it feels the pressure of the water on that side, given by

$$F_p=p(r)A-p(r+dr)A$$
where $p(r)$ is the pressure and again $A$ the area. This force acts in the radial direction.

And.. that's it. There are no other forces. The other direction is balanced by the syringe's wall.

We can now use $F=ma$ as

$$p(r)A-p(r+dr)A = dm a$$

but.. what is the acceleration $a$? It can't be 0 because the syring is moving...

Because the syringe is rotating at constant speed, we have a radial acceleration that is changing the direction of movement of the mass of water, given by $a_c=-\omega^2r$, pointing towards the center.
$$p(r)A-p(r+dr)A = dm a_c = -dm\omega^2r $$

Notice that, you could move $ma_c$ on the left side and end up in a system where the acceleration is $0$ (the reference system of the syring) with an *apparent* force $ma_c$. That's the "centrifugal force".

Anyways, we end up with
$$p(r)A-p(r+dr)A = -dm \omega^2r$$
we then write $dm=\rho A dr$ and then
$$p(r)A-p(r+dr)A =-\rho A \omega^2r$$
simplify a bit..
$$p(r)-p(r+dr)=-\rho\omega^2 r$$

We know expand $p(r+dr)\approx p(r)+dp/dr$ where $dp/dr$ is the derivative of p with respect to the radius.
We then simplify $p(r)-p(r+dr)=p(r)-p(r)-dp/dr$ and end up with a differential equation

$${dp\over dr}=\rho\omega^2 r$$

which has the solution

$$p(r)=p_0+\rho\omega^2{r^2\over 2}$$

where $p_0$ is the pressure at $r=0$.

Notice that:

1. it does not depend on $A$ i.e. if you want to include the needle you just plug in the new value of the radius $r$!
2. a long enough syringe will reach any pressure